# spaces between arabic characters in android

Tags: android, fonts, arabic

I am trying to create an application which has arabic in it. I used number of different fonts but in vain. I am facing the problem as depicted in the screenshot attached. Either the characters are overlapping or there are spaces in between the characters. any help would be much appreciated. I used 4 different type of fonts and neither of these fonts are being displayed properly. I am using 4.1.2 as the version (API 16) for the test app.

[image]

Comment: try to remove these char 'ُ ' from where space appear.and test app

Comment: Without knowing your code no one can help you

Comment: Leon_SFS: If you closely see the problem occurs when there are ARAABs above arabic characters.

Mohsen Afshin: Are you serious? I created 4 text views in XML and added text in those text views statically. Do you really need code now? Here is the XML for one text view amongst those four:

<TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvArabic"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="خَتَمَ اللَّهُ عَلَىٰ قُلُوبِهِمْ وَعَلَىٰ سَمْعِهِمْ ۖ وَعَلَىٰ أَبْصَارِهِمْ غِشَاوَةٌ ۖ وَلَهُمْ عَذَابٌ عَظِيمٌ"
        android:textSize="36sp" />

Comment: it's obviously! there is some ARAABs that can not be place on some character,try to reshape your text and put it on textbox

Comment: what do you mean by reshape? I am talking about API 16 and it supports arabic!! Why do i need to reshape?